# Swagger url generated json is missing "securityschemes" component

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, springfox, springdoc

My generated swagger.json is missing the securitySchemes component. When I copy the url json and paste it in swagger editor, I get -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihpp4.png)

The generated yaml in swagger.json file is like below -

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Test YAML
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: 'localhost'
    description: Inferred Url
tags:
  - name: device-controller
    description: the device API
  - name: api-controller
    description: API
paths:
  /api/device:
    get:
      tags:
        - ABCD
      summary: Device SUMMARY.
      description: Device DESCRIPTION.
      operationId: getDevice
      parameters:
        - name: X-Request-ID
          in: header
          description: 'request Id, will return in the response headers, and appear in logs'
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: list of commands set
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CommandSet'
        '400':
          description: Bad request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
        '404':
          description: The specified resource was not found
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
      security:
        - BasicAuth: []
components:
  schemas:
    CommandSet:
      title: CommandSet
      required:
        - name
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
          example: 07da6fd8-5abc-4dc4-bcec-df309d123d17
        name:
          type: string
          example: Deny
    Error:
      title: Error
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          example: '400'
        message:
          type: string
          example: Bad Request
```

---

**it is missing**

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
```

---

I have defined under resource folder the following yaml file

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Policy APIs
  description: 'Policy APIs for manage Policy Sets, authorization policies, authentication policies, and policy elements.'
  version: 1.0.0
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: 'https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html'
  contact:
    email: abc@gmail.com
servers:
  - url: 'https://{server}/v1/policy'
    variables:
      server:
        default: localhost
        description: The host where the API is rooted
security:
  - BasicAuth: []
paths:
  /device-admin/command-sets:
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/XRequestIdHeader'
    get:
      summary: Device Admin - Return list of command sets.
      description: Device Admin - Return list of command sets.
      operationId: getDeviceAdminCommandSets
      tags:
        - Device Administration - Command Set
      responses:
        '200':
          description: list of commands set
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CommandSet'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
        '404':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/NotFound'
components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
  parameters:
    XRequestIdHeader:
      in: header
      name: X-Request-ID
      description: 'request Id, will return in the response headers, and appear in logs'
      schema:
        type: string
      required: false
  responses:
    BadRequest:
      description: Bad request
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
    NotFound:
      description: The specified resource was not found
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
          example: '{code: 404, message: The specified resource was not found}'
  schemas:
    CommandSet:
      type: object
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          example: DenyAllCommands
          description: Command used in Device Admin authorization policies
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
          example: 07da6fd8-5abc-4dc4-bcec-df309dbf4d17
    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          example: 400
        message:
          type: string
          example: Bad Request
```

How to get the securitySchemes component in the swagger url definition.
I am using OAS 3.x and the openAPI generator tool to generate the java code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe the following will be helpful to some readers. The openAPI generator generates a class named `SpringDocConfiguration`, which bears a `@Configuration` attribute. This class  contains the line of code that calls the `addSecuritySchemes` method for configuring your security scheme component. If you set a breakpoint to that line, and debug the application start, and the breakpoint is not hit, then probably this class is not picked up (scanned) by Spring during startup.

This had been the case for us. We fixed it by specifying the package name of the class in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
invokerPackage.set("${rootProject.name}.security")
```

If you don't find the generated class `SpringDocConfiguration`, or if the code line with `addSecuritySchemes` is missing, then check your configuration for the springdoc-openapi code generator.

Answer (score -1):

In OpenAPI 3.0, you use the servers array to specify one or more base URLs for your API. servers replaces the host, basePath and schemes keywords used in OpenAPI 2.0. Each server has an url and an optional Markdown-formatted description.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

[Add server array in swagger spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDnUl.png)

Comment: The `securitySchemes` keyword exists in OpenAPI 3.0, and this is a different concept than the `schemes` keyword in OpenAPI 2.0. How does your answer relate to the OP's question?